# ADDITION of values of the specific key from NSMutableDictonary (Using NSPredicate)

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, nsmutabledictionary

I have following JSON response which has been stored in `NSMutableDictonary`. I want to addition of all the **price** of **special_item**.

```
{
    "order_id": "1",
    "order_name": "xyz",
    "order_item": [
        {
            "item_id": "1",
            "item_name": "myone",
            "special_item": [
                {
                    "s_item_id": "1",
                    "price": "10"
                },
                {
                    "s_item_id": "2",
                    "price": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "item_id": "2",
            "item_name": "mytwo",
            "special_item": [
                {
                    "s_item_id": "11",
                    "price": "15"
                },
                {
                    "s_item_id": "22",
                    "price": "110"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to do addition of all the **price** using `NSPredicate` ? or How can I get array of all the **price** values using `NSPredicate`?(e.g : [@10,@100,@15,@110]) 
 
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe with combining `valueForKeyPath:` and `@sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so simple

you can try below code

```
NSArray *arr = [dix valueForKeyPath:@"order_item.special_item.price"];
long total = 0;
for (id price in arr) {
    if ([price isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        total += [[price valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] longValue];
    }
    else {
        total += [price longValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger *total=0;
NSArray *arr=[NSDictionary objectForKey=@"order_item"];
for(NSDictionary *dic in arr){
    NSArray *array=[dic objectForKey=@"special_item"];
    for(NSDictionary *d in array){
        total=total+[[d objectForKey=@"price"] intValue];
    }
}
NSLog("Total:- %d",total);
```